# Erlang search for specific element in list of records

Tags: erlang

I have defined 2 records:

```
-record(state, {port = 9921,
                clients = []
               }
        ).

-record (client, {pid,
                  acc}).
```

And I have created variable which contains port and 3 records:

```
 State = #state{port = 9921, 
                clients = []},
 NewClient1 = #client{pid = "A", acc = <<85>>},
 NewClient2 = #client{pid = "B", acc = <<73>>},
 NewClient3 = #client{pid = "C", acc = <<56>>},
 NewState = State#state{clients = [NewClient1 , NewClient2, NewClient3]},
```

NewState now contains

```
#state{port = 9921,
   clients = [#client{pid = "A",acc = <<"U">>},
              #client{pid = "B",acc = <<"I">>},
              #client{pid = "C",acc = <<25>>}]}
```

My question is, I want to search record state for some specific pid, example: I want to get true for function find ("B", NewState) and false for function find ("Z", NewState). What is most easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use fact, that `#client.pid` contain an index of `pid` in record tuple.

So simplest and most efficient (up to like 100 clients then you should change data format of `#state.clients` to map or use ets) solution is

```
lists:keyfind(Pid, #client.pid, State#state.clients) =/= false
```

See

```
1> rd(state, {port, clients}).              
state
2> rd(client, {pid, acc}).
client
3> State = #state{port=9921, clients=[#client{pid = "A", acc = <<85>>}, #client{pid = "B", acc = <<73>>}, #client{pid = "C", acc = <<56>>}]}.
#state{port = 9921,
       clients = [#client{pid = "A",acc = <<"U">>},
                  #client{pid = "B",acc = <<"I">>},
                  #client{pid = "C",acc = <<"8">>}]}
4> #client.pid.         
2
5> Find = fun(Pid, State) -> lists:keyfind(Pid, #client.pid, State#state.clients) =/= false end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.50752066>
6> Find("B", State).
true
7> Find("Z", State).
false
```

Answer (score 0):

The record syntax allows you to access to the client list with:

```
Clients = NewState#state.clients
```

then you can use the function lists:any/2 to check if a condition is true for at least one element of a list:

```
lists:any(Pred, List)
```

putting all together

```
found(Test, NewState) ->
    lists:any(fun(X) -> X#client.pid == Test end, NewState#state.clients).
```